# How to tie all the questions together and get a final score in Android Studio quiz app?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to figure out how to tie all the questions together and get a correct final score 10/10 or 11/10 for getting the bonus question correct. I am sure I am overthinking it but I am genuinely stuck and will appreciate any help that I receive.

I am a complete beginner at Java and trying to figure out how to go about this and I am sure my code can definitely be simplified and I have complicated it very much.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution will be to use a SharedPref variable. Update the SharedPref every time user answers a question.

Another method will be to have a global variable inside your application class and update that.

Comment: I do have a global variable and I am using it in the methods but I am stuck in a sense that I don't think I am using the method correctly to get the actual score. I hope that made sense.

Comment: you should have a single generic method which accept a question and the answer options. You just need to call this method with different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Recently,we built a similar thing.
The way we did was to use SqLite .
We had a list of questions and each question with 4 options stored inside the app in a database .
Later , upon answering of each question we check the correct option and update the score of the user it it's the correct option (Boolean).
Finally we calculate the total no of true values against the member I'd.